# How to determine the average of two strings?

Tags: algorithms

Given two strings $s$ and $t$, is there a way to find a string $a$ such that $d(a,s)=d(a,t)$, where $d$ is the Levenshtein distance?

I am sure that a genetic algorithm would work pretty well but I would prefer an explicit solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The computation of the Levenshtein distance is a classic example of application of [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Iterative_with_full_matrix).

In this algorithm, you modify iteratively a matrix that denotes the distance between two prefixes of the two words. A modification occurs according to the following formula:

```
d[i, j] := minimum(d[i-1, j] + 1,                   // deletion
                   d[i, j-1] + 1,                   // insertion
                   d[i-1, j-1] + substitutionCost)  // substitution
```

You can then keep track of what of the three operations gave its value to `d[i, j]`, to know what steps are necessary to transform the first word into the second.

Now to find the "average" of $s$ and $t$, you can:

- if $d(s, t) = 2k$, then just do half of the modifications needed from $s$, to get the word $a$
- if $d(s, t) = 2k+1$, then do $k$ modifications and add a $*$ instead of the $k+1$-th operation and get $a$

In both cases, $d(s, a) = d(a, t) = \left\lceil\frac{d(s, t)}{2}\right\rceil$ which is optimal.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the $d(s,t)$ additions, deletions, and edits that transform $s$ in $t$.

Let $*$ be a new character.

Instead of inserting the prescribed character, insert $*$. Instead of deleting a character, change it to $*$. Instead of replacing a character with the prescribed character, replace it with $*$.

---

As an example, the edit distance between "mars" and "toast" is 4, and the corresponding edits are:

- Change "m" in "t"
- Add "o"
- Leave "a" unchanged
- Delete "r"
- Leave "s" unchanged
- Add "t"

Replace these steps with:

- Change "m" in $*$
- Add $*$
- Leave "a" unchanged
- Change "r" in $*$
- Leave "s" unchanged
- Add $*$

Applying these steps yields "$**$a$*$s$*$".

Comment: Might you give an example?

Comment: @Victor, see the edited answer.

Comment: I accepted your answer since it fully answers the question but I guess I should have ask to minimise `d(a,s)` as well as having the equality, anyway thaks